# Rejected Edit - Since When Is Modifying "Implicitely" To "Implicitly" Considered "superfluous"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I made an edit, which I would rather not directly reference at this time, where one of the changes I made, for clarity/correction, was modifying to the use of the word "implicitely" which is clearly not considered proper English by web sites such as Google:

"Did you mean: **implicitly**"

--or--

"Did you mean: **define:implicitly**"

Not only was this edit rejected by the same person who used the incorrect spelling, this part on its own is actually minor, and I would have left it there; however, the more major issue, for which I am posting is, this individual didn't even fix this (minor?) spelling issue themselves. Aren't some of these, rejecting an edit to one's own post, let alone not fixing the post, conflicts of interest in some way (a person blind to their own error in one case, can be blind to the same error in another/same case later)? This individual took the time reject my edit with the **canned response**:

"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

and, yet, didn't have the decency to correct a very simple spelling error?

This is intended as an honest question and I do hope to receive an honest answer (or answers).

Comment: Besides the spelling mistake, the edit in question isn't something of a very significant value. The OP who rejected the edit may have thought the same and simply not have picked up on the spelling mistake.

Comment: There's two things here: 1. Such a small edit shouldn't really go into the review queue, so most reviewers would have rejected it. 2. Since the OP rejected it (and I'm assuming he's not a reviewer); I believe that it was the wrong decision to reject the edit - as it wasn't necessarily wasting their time - unless they rejected on principle. However, it's their post, and ultimately, they are able to decide what edits they want/do not want in their post - as long as the content is not breaking site rules.

Comment: The change you are complaining about not being made, aren't most of the changes you suggested in [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9377070) which mostly comes across as changing one word to another for no reason, unnecessarily bolding words and inserting half a sentence that doesn't really read well. People don't typically read the edit reason when they can see what appears to have been changed.

Comment: Calling the users "decency" into question seems like a massive over-reaction to their decision, when it is entirely within their rights to reject your edit that -- other than a simple spelling mistake most peoples brains would read over and not notice -- doesn't improve the post in *any way*.

Comment: You complain about a typo and then try to add text with a word missing? "It is important note that ..." should have been "It is important **to** note that ..."

Comment: When someone rejects a minor edit only to make the exact same edit themselves, someone calls them out on denying the original editor their "deserved" rep. When someone rejects a minor edit without applying the same edit, their decency gets called into question. **You just can't win.**

Comment: @BoltClock The only winning move...

Comment: Maybe the OP didn't even notice the spelling "fix" in your suggestion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior

Answer (score 23):

As the author of the post in question:

I didn't see the spelling error of *implicitly*, and 
after writing this here I'm going to correct that.
(then this part of the problem should be solved, right?)

What I *did* see was the unnecessary bold marking, and after seeing (too) many 
edits where only the text style of some words is changed, I immediately rejected it. 
Yeah, I should've taken some time to actually read it. ...

However, after reading it more carefully now, my opinion what to do with it 
(given the other changes, the fact that it is a queue review etc.) hasn't changed. [and apparently many commenters believe too that *Reject* was ok]

About "wasting my time" because I didn't do that in the review queue: I got a notification that one of my posts has a pending edit, and I looked at it ... I don't think it's wasting time just because my review counter won't increase.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `´` instead of `'` all the time? That's the wrong character, as far as I know. As an aside, your review-counter *did* increase for it. That's the only way sub-2K's can review suggested edits or non-mods can rack up more than their 20 reviews of suggested edits.

Comment: @Deduplicator About the reviews: Ok, then it was even less time-wasting. About the ' : Bad habit...